# terraform module with resource choice

Tags: module, terraform

how to rewrite the module for creating a resource group so that you can choose whether it should be with a lock or without a lock resource ?

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.rg_name    
  location = var.rg_location 
}

resource "random_id" "random" {
  keepers = {
    id = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "lock" {
  name       = "resource-group-lock-${random_id.random.hex}"
  scope      = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  lock_level = var.lock_level
}
```

resource selection is possible ?

Comment: So `lock_level` is optional?

Comment: lock_level specifies the type of lock,
It would be better if it stayed as it is, the module will be more flexible

Comment: What specifically in the posted terraform code are you trying to make optional? The entire `azurerm_management_lock` resource? Have you looked at the `count` meta-argument in Terraform? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count